# SQL Query is not return any response for two query

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am doing a powershell script for query the database and extract the value from my database table, the script will query two different database table. But i found out the second query is not returning any result 
This is my script

```
$query1="select  no,b.store,b.Name, b.ID,a.location from 
(SELECT *,(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 91 + 1)as ID
from table_A ) a 
left join table_B b
on a.ID = b.ID 
where a.firstname is not null "
$com=$connection.CreateCommand()
$com.CommandText=$uery1
$r1 = $com.ExecuteReader()
add-content D:\test_$currentDate.log "The reader : $r1"
while ($r1.read())
{
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $r1.FieldCount; $i++)
      {
         #assign value to the respective variable 
         # working fine for this section
         # value assign correctly and database return result
      }
          Add-Content D:\test_$currentDate.log  "The no before generate the email : $no"
          $query2="SELECT test_table ('"+$no+"') " 
          # $no is the value return from database for the first query
          $com2=$connection.CreateCommand()
          $com2.CommandText=$query2
          $result=$command.ExecuteReader()
          Add-Content D:\test__$currentDate.log  "The query2 : $query2"

          Add-Content D:\test_$currentDate.log  "The com2 : $com2"
          add-content D:\test_$currentDate.log "result : $result" 
       while ($result.read())
            {   
                Add-Content D:\test_$currentDate.log  "This is a test"
               # assign value from database 
           }

}
```

I found out `This is a test` is not update in my log file which i suspect the `$result` variable is empty. i tried execute the query from the SQL console, it was able to return result for both query,the sample output is here

```
The reader : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader  
The no before generate the email : XXXXX
The query2 : SELECT test_table ('"+$no+"') 
The com2 : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
result : System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal
```

both of the query pointed to same database,the `$query2` is a scalar-valued function and i am wondering what is the different between `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader` and `System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal` that return from database.

Comment: Your code sample doesn't look like it could write the output you've provided - the line ```Add-Content D:\test__$currentDate.log  "The query2 : $query"``` references a variable ```$query``` which isn't defined in your code, so I don't think your output could contain ```The query2 : SELECT test_table ('"+$no+"') ```. Could you confirm the code sample and / or output are correct?

Comment: i updated the code, i have to hide up some confidential detail in the code. I found the solution to my question. Trigger scalar value function will require other method

Comment: 1) Your code is open to SQL injection problems/attacks. 2) You have a typo when executing query1, which may be resulting in query2 not being executed at all. `$com.CommandText=$uery1` is missing a `q`

Comment: Can you confirm you’ve actually tried executing your example code? As well as @alroc’s comment I can see at least one other inconsistency that implies your code as-is couldn’t have generated the exact output you’ve posted.